# Accessing same variables in Verilog on different clocks

Tags: verilog, clock, system-verilog

I have a 50Mhz master clock **clk** and from that I have a derived **baudClock** clock which runs at 9600bps.

I have a transmitter module that I want to follow a state machine flow every **baudClock**.

The transmitter module receives strings from an external module/testbench and puts them into a queue. I want the state machine to take an item from the queue and then reduce **queueCount** by one.

On the other hand, I would like to be able to add an item to the queue on a **clk** cycle.

I cannot implement something such as that below because I would then be assigning **queueCount** from 2 always processes (resulting in multiple driver errors).

```
always_ff @(posedge clk )
begin
  if( addToQueue )
  begin
    if( queueCount < MAX_ELEMENTS )
    begin
      textQueue[ queueCount ] = myString;
      queueCount ++;
    end
  end
end

always_ff @(posedge baudClock )
begin
  unique case( state )
    IDLE         : HandleIdle();
    GETNEXT      : HandleGetNextString();  // Decreases queueCount
    SENDSTART    : HandleSendStart();
    SENDDATA     : HandleSendData();
    SENDBYTEDONE : HandleSendByteDone();
  endcase
end
```

How would I go about doing this? ie. What's the best way to share variables in reading/writing or producer/consumer scenarios?

Comment: `baudTick` is not really a variable ... it is a signal

Comment: Are you planning to implement this in an FPGA, a CPLD, an ASIC, or what?

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm planning on implementing this in an FPGA.

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks for the answer. I was more or less doing what you'd suggested, just generating/counting/strobing the baud signal outside of the module. Sorry if my terminology is poor - I am a software developer and this is very new to me.

Comment: @ThePhoton I guess the other thing I need to be mindful of is that an actual 9600 bps clock is going to keep the baudClock high for many master clock cycles.. So by "strobe" I guess you mean that I should only have the "strobe" high for one master clock cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments you said this is for implementation in an FPGA.

In that case, you should reconsider your architecture.

Instead of dividing down your 50 MHz master clock and having a second 9600 Hz clock, use the 50 MHz clock to drive your 9600 Hz logic, but use a strobe signal to enable that logic.

```
reg str9600;
reg [12:0] str_ct;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    // Generate 9600 baud strobe
    if (reset) begin
        str_ct <= 0;
        str9600 <= 0;
    end
    else if (str_ct == 5208) begin
        str_ct <= 0;
        str9600 <= 1;
    end
    else begin
        str_ct <= str_ct + 1;
        str9600 <= 0;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
   // Do 9600 baud operations when enabled by strobe
   if (reset) 
        // reset stuff
   else if(str9600) 
        // do 9600 baud stuff
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    // do 50 MHz stuff
    // queue management goes here
end
```

Now your queue becomes part of the 50 MHz logic, with the `str9600` signal as an input, telling it whether something can be pulled out of the queue, but able to add to the queue on any 50 MHz clock edge.